# Button Sliding Ionic 3

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to apply the sliding effect with these buttons. I have the following html:

```
<ion-row class="row-two-button">
   <ion-col class="button-group">
     <button ion-button round color="secondary" [ngClass]="{dark: travelDestinationA, light: travelDestinationB}" (click)="changeDirectionTravel()">
       <ion-icon name="md-bus"></ion-icon>
         Centro
     </button>
     <button ion-button round color="secondary" [ngClass]="{dark: travelDestinationB, light: travelDestinationA}" (click)="changeDirectionTravel()">
       <ion-icon name="md-bus"></ion-icon>
         Bairro
     </button>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

[image]

I need to make the slide effect in scss. I'm using ionic 3. If it does not work with my html code how can I do it with another type, a div or something like

When sliding it is also necessary to perform a function in angular 2 or angular 4

Comment: Slide how? like the slide to unlock?

Comment: Exactly what I need as if it were to block ios

Comment: hmm. not sure how to do that , but i think you are going to want to use gestures, specifically the pan gesture https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures

Comment: Great one of the problems solved on the slide effect do you know about anything?

Comment: What I needed is the swiped, it takes the event to slip, but I need to animate it with a css that accompanies the swiped.

Comment: Not sure but you might need to bind the pan x value to the button somehow, maybe changing the margin value based on the pan value. Its an interesting question. Hope you come right

Comment: Maybe you need [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch)

Comment: Actually no, what I need is exactly this movement, however I'm doing it using 2 buttons and 1 div. I think the way I'm using it is impossible to do this. Because in case it would be necessary a css of in and another of out in the buttons. I really do not know if I can do this with the two buttons.